# Install travis command line windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, version, travis-ci

I would like to install the command line tool of travis (https://rubygems.org/gems/travis) in order to set up travis properly. I do have a windows machine, I installed ruby and gem.

```
$ ruby --version
  ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [i386-mingw32]

$ gem --version
  2.4.5
```

When installing (in verbose mode) the installation fails to fetch a dependency that does not exist.

```
$ gem install travis -V
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=travis
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?    gems=addressable,backports,faraday,faraday_middleware,gh,highline,launchy,
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=coderay,ethon,json,method_source,multi_json,multipart-post,net-http-p,slop,websocket,win32console
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=ffi
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.9.12.6-x86-mingw32.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.9.12.6-x86-mingw32.gemspec.rz
404 Not Found
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
bad response Not Found 404 (https://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.9.12.6-x86-mingw32.gemspec.rz)
```

Also installing pry manually (in various versions) fails

```
$ gem install pry  -V
 HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
      200 OK
 GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=pry
      200 OK
 GET https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.10.1-x86-mingw32.gemspec.rz
      302 Moved Temporarily
 GET https://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.10.1-x86-mingw32.gemspec.rz
     404 Not Found
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
bad response Not Found 404 (https://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.10.1-x86-mingw32.gemspec.rz)
```

The file that gem is trying to fetch is the following:

https://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.10.1-x86-mingw32.gemspec.rz

Therefore my question: Is there any other possibility to get this gem or any other way to run `gem install travis` on windows?

Thanks a lot and cheers,
Fabian

Answer (score 2):

[Known issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1120)

As a workaround you can downgrade gem:

```
gem update --system 2.4.4 
gem install pry
```

Comment: should that by --system instead of ---system? (two dashes instead of three)